# Is there any way to limit integer datatype value range

Tags: c

I am trying to give PWM to a fan
so i can give value (called fanduty in my case) from 0 to 100 only.
but uint8_t has values 0 to 256.

```
    if(Temp > 40)                         
                     Fan_Duty ++;
    else if(Temp < 40)                                           
                     Fan_Duty --;
    else
                     //do nothing
```

so Fan_duty value go from 0 to 256 whereas while reducing it 
it starts from 256 and goes to 0,from 256 to 100 no use and hence it wastes precious time,
so i want that value doesnot go above hundred .
how to limit an integer range ?

Comment: You can easily create a function to *clamp* the value within a range.

Comment: Fan_Duty = Target_Fan_Speed * 256 / 100?

Comment: If you increment the value after 99, what is the expected behaviour. Should the value stay at 99 or should it roll over to 0. Also if you decrement it below zero, do you want the new value to be 99?

Comment: Increment only `if(Fan_Duty < 100)` and decrement only `if(Fan_Duty > 0)`.

Comment: A `uint8_t` will have values from `0` to `255`, not `256`.    In any event, if you want to limit the values check the value before incrementing or decrementing it, and disallow unwanted changes.   Bear in mind that decrementing a `uint8_t`  variable with value `0` will give a result of `255`  and that incrementing one with value `255` will give a result of `0`.

Comment: A PWM has a resolution of 8, 16 or 32 bits. In your case it is apparently 8 bits. Therefore the duty cycle can only be expressed as a raw value between 0 and 255. That's the only thing that makes sense if you program the PWM driver itself. Or is this some PC stuff with some sort of "muddy logic" API in between? What system is this? What generates the PWM?

Comment: @RishikeshRaje it should not rollover to 0 after 99 or 99 after 0

Comment: @Lundin microcontroller is generating pwm using a timer, and i am providing 0 to 100 as percentage of PWM signal

Comment: @G.ONE In this case, you have a good solution with Mike

Comment: @G.ONE So you have some manner of data protocol that you send to a microcontroller?

Answer (score 3):

First check the value of `Fan_Duty` and then increment / decrement it.

```
if (Temp > 40)
{                        
    if (Fan_Duty < 100)
    {
        Fan_Duty ++;
    }
}
else if (Temp < 40)
{
    if (Fan_Duty > 0)
    {
        Fan_Duty --;
    }
}
else
{
      //do nothing
}
```